# Get number of reallocated sectors on harddrive without S.M.A.R.T

Tags: windows-7, windows, hard-drive, smart, hard-drive-failure

Is that possible? There is no S.M.A.R.T. information retrievable (used *HD Tune* to check that).

The background is that I want to check if the number of reallocated sectors on the harddrive changes after a run of checkdsk with full test mode because we encounter some strange problems we assume that the problems lie with bad sectors on the harddisk.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If there is no S.M.A.R.T data then the hdd isn't keeping track of it or at the very least its not exposed.  You might have more luck with a program like `Spin Rite 6` instead of `chkdisk`

Comment: @Ramhound: You should/could post this as an answer :)

Comment: I would but it likely would just recieved downvotes from people out of spite. I make a point not to post very many answers on this site for this reason.  Of course S.M.A.R.T has been around for more then 10 years so the likelyhood of you having a hdd with S.M.A.R.T support is very unlikely.

Comment: OK, i see, no problem.

Answer (score 0):

The vast majority of modern hard drives record S.M.A.R.T. data.

A couple of things you can try to retrieve it:

- Try a different program  (e.g., [CrystalDiskInfo](http://crystalmark.info/software/CrystalDiskInfo/index-e.html) or [Passmark disk checkup](http://www.passmark.com/products/diskcheckup.htm)).
- If your hard drive is external, disassemble it and connect it to a SATA port.

  (This will void your warranty.)
- If your hard drive is internal, connect it to a different SATA port.

Comment: I forgot to say that we have a two disk RAID system. Does that change anything?

Comment: @nepa - Yes.  That is the reason you have no S.M.A.R.T data.

Comment: Software RAID shouldn't, hardware RAID probably will. Are you using an onboard or hardware RAID controller? If yes, which one?